# Words with the same letter present three times consecutively

Tags: demande-de-mot

The only word I can think of that has the same letter repeated (at least) three times consecutively is `créée` such as in ...

> La nouvelle fonction qu'il a créée [..]

Are there other examples?

Comment: let me simply point out that in French é and e are not really the same letter..

Comment: Well yeah. The alphabet still contains only 26 letters. There are no special places for é, è, à, î and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of Course there are. You should check wikipédia for some examples

See : [Wikipédia - Mots avec trois lettres identiques à la suite](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Curiosit%C3%A9s_linguistiques_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Mots_avec_trois_lettres_identiques_.C3.A0_la_suite)

As precised in this article (which might not record every example), these are "all past particpates from first group verbs in their feminin form and their plurals".